# SQL - Fill one table from fields of another table

Tags: sql, select, database-design, insert, field

I have an **empty** SQL table with the following Design:
**table1**

```
MsgName_ID      bigint   
MsgName_Type    nvarchar(10)     
MsgName_CurID   nvarchar(100)    
MsgName_Name    nvarchar(50)     
MsgName_Meaning nvarchar(1000)    
MsgName_Note    varchar(50)  
MsgName_Gender  varchar(10)  
MsgName_Origin  nvarchar(100)     
MsgName_Active  bit  
MsgName_Created datetime
```

and another **full** table with the following design:
**table2**

```
Name    nvarchar(255)
Meaning nvarchar(255)
Gender  nvarchar(255)   
Origin  nvarchar(255)
```

I want to fill the empty table with
`Table1.MsgName_Name= Table2.Name` , `Table1.MsgName_Meaning=Table2.Meaning` , `table1.MsgName_Gender=Table2.Gender` , `table1.MsgName_Origin=table2.Origin`

All the other fields have a default value.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
Insert into table1 (MsgName_Name,MsgName_Meaning,MsgName_Gender,MsgName_Origin)
Select Name,Meaning,Gender,Origin from table2
```